# Food styles missing from OpenGraph restaurant place data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to get a restaurant's food styles in an OpenGraph query?  I'm referring to e.g. "Food styles: American (New)" on http://www.facebook.com/pages/Evoo-Restaurant/110407682334493?sk=info

This is editable place page metadata but doesn't appear in the response http://graph.facebook.com/110407682334493 nor in the available FQL fields.  Has it simply been left out?

Thanks,
Jonathan