# Food Styles field from Facebook OpenGraph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

Is it possible to get the food styles from the facebook Open Graph API? For some reason I can't seem to get it from the fb_graph gem and was wondering if it was just not available from facebook's perspective.

Comment: I’ve read questions like this before and had a look around, but I wasn’t able to find this information anywhere with the API, neither directly or by FQL. So as long as no one comes and shows the way to do it, I’d say No, this is currently not available.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by 'food styles' in this context?

Comment: For example "Korean", "Japanese", "Chinese", "French" are all food styles

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is available as part of the API, check this listing - http://www.facebook.com/pages/Evoo-Restaurant/110407682334493?sk=info and check the graph - http://graph.facebook.com/110407682334493

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot get this field from the graph API nor directly by using FQL.

If you look at the [available fields](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#fields) for a Page, it is not listed. The doc also states:

> Pages may also contain other (or additional) category-specific fields.

However, if you use the APIs to get the info for a restaurant Page, the Food Styles are left out, as the links from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525705/food-styles-missing-from-opengraph-restaurant-place-data) demonstrate.

Here is another example where you can see that the info is unavailable, which is for a restaurant in Tokyo:
http://graph.facebook.com/hakusyu

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible (as at the time of writing). But it should be. I filed a bug.

In the future, when something like this appears to be askew, please do so too: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs